# Detect significant location changes flutter

Tags: flutter, location

I created a basic app which can detect location changes and show the data in flutter. I want to upload data to Firebase Realtime Database. But I don't want a network call when each and every single change occurs. I have latitude and longitude upto 7 decimal points. What would be a resonable limit of location change?

The reasonable limit also depend on where the user is(need more precision in city). So is there any package that helps by considering this factor also?

This is the current code:

```
return StreamBuilder<LocationData>(
        stream: location.onLocationChanged,
        initialData:current,
        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<LocationData> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return Center(
              child:SizedBox(
                width:200,
                height:200,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text("LOCATION",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                    Text(snapshot.data!.longitude.toString()+" - LONGITUDE",style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                    Text(snapshot.data!.latitude.toString()+" - LATITUDE",style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }else{
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }
      );
```